# Subparser argparse "error: too few arguments"

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

```
# bird.py
from argparse import ArgumentParser, SUPPRESS

parser = ArgumentParser(argument_default=SUPPRESS)
parser.add_argument('--dead', action='store_true')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
subparser = subparsers.add_parser('parrot', parents=[parser], add_help=False)
subparser.add_argument('--volts', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

The script `bird.py` above works as expected on Python 3.  But on Python 2.7 it won't parse arguments:

```
$ python3 bird.py parrot --volts 4000000
Namespace(volts=4000000)
$ python2 bird.py parrot --volts 4000000
usage: bird.py parrot [-h] [--dead] [--volts VOLTS] {parrot} ...
bird.py parrot: error: too few arguments
```

There aren't any py3-only features used in the code as far as I can see. Why doesn't it work the same? How to update this code so the CLI can also support Python 2.7, **without modifying its Python 3 behavior in any way**?

Comment: The latest Py3 lets us specify `required=True` in the `add_subparsers` command, making it behave more like Py2 (but be sure to set `dest='cmd'` as well).  Py3 has a more informative missing argument message.  There isn't a way of turning off required subparsers in Py2.

Comment: Does '--dead parrot --volts 200' actually set `dead=True'?  I think the `default=False` in the subparser overwrites any value set in the main parser.  Defining an argument that works in both the main and subparser may be nice from a user standpoint, but is tricky to implement in a reliable way.

Comment: Hmm, actually it doesn't work in this MCVE for the reason you've described. In real case I was using `argparse.SUPPRESS` which I mistakenly thought wasn't relevant here - I've updated the code to make a better MCVE.

Comment: You could try using a local copy of `argparse.py`.  A py3 version should run in py2 with just a couple of changes (for example reverting a `yield from` back to its original form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parents` copies more than you want it to. `parents` tries to copy the parents' subparsers, which ends up trying to make `subparser` a subparser of itself. On Python 3, subparsers default to being optional, so the fact that `parrot` didn't get its own `parrot` isn't an error. On Python 2, subparsers are required, so `parrot` needs its own `parrot` and complains about not getting it. (I would be unsurprised if even more than this gets corrupted, considering that you're modifying the parent parser by adding a subparser while you're trying to use it as a parent.)

Rather than trying to use `parser` as a parent of its own subparsers, instead create a separate parent parser and use it as a parent of both the top-level parser and the parrot subparser:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

shared = ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
shared.add_argument('--dead', action='store_true')

parser = ArgumentParser(parents=[shared])
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
subparser = subparsers.add_parser('parrot', parents=[shared])
subparser.add_argument('--volts', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Results:

```
$ python2 bird.py parrot --volts 4000000
Namespace(dead=False, volts=4000000)
$ python3.6 bird.py parrot --volts 4000000
Namespace(dead=False, volts=4000000)
```

However, there are more problems, because you're adding `--dead` options to both the parent and the child, and they're trying to write to the same place. The child appears to take priority:

```
$ python bird.py --dead parrot
Namespace(dead=False, volts=None)
$ python bird.py parrot --dead
Namespace(dead=True, volts=None)
```

Giving both the top-level parser and the subparser a `--dead` option might make sense if they had different values of `dest`, or if they had an action other than `store_true`, but the way you have things now, it doesn't make much sense. If you want different values of `dest`, I don't think you can use the `parents` mechanism for this.

Answer (score 0):

This error come from `parents` argument in `subparsers.add_parser()` call.

```
# bird.py
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--dead', action='store_true')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
subparser = subparsers.add_parser('parrot', add_help=False)
subparser.add_argument('--volts', type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

then

```
$ python scratch.py parrot --volts 1000
Namespace(dead=False, volts=1000)
```

The reason is that using `subparsers.add_parser()` create a new parser calling call `ArgumentParser`'s constructor:

```
class ArgumentParser(_AttributeHolder, _ActionsContainer):
    """Object for parsing command line strings into Python objects.

    Keyword Arguments:
        - [...]
        - parents -- Parsers whose arguments should be copied into this one
    """
```

Calling `subparsers.add_parser('parrot', parents=[parser], add_help=False)` will copy the root parser arguments into the new subparser one, including the subparser itself. This lead to an infinite parsing loop that cannot be resolved.

Comment: `parents` created a recursive subparser.  `python3 stack53158180.py parrot parrot parrot` works.  Py2 also recurses, but still hits the missing subparser error, just further down the line.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah, I just understood that after doing a quick debug session and seeing the documentation for ArgumentParser's `parents` argument

Comment: Removing parents is unacceptable because the behavior is modified.  See the difference with `python3 bird.py parrot --dead --volts 4000000`.

Comment: Define a separate `parent` parser with just `dead`, and use that with both the main and subparsers.  Using 'working-parser' as a parent has been problematic in other contexts.